# Distributed push relabel with changing graph topology

Tags: distributed-systems, network-flow

There is at least one ([1](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=4837430613606816432&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)) distributed version propsosed for the push-relabel maximum-flow algorithm. I wonder if and how this algorithm can cope with nodes leaving or enterig the graph during runtime. Is there any work about this?

[1](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=4837430613606816432&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) Andrew V Goldberg and Robert E Tarjan. *A new approach to the
maximum-flow problem*. Journal of the ACM (JACM), 35(4):921–940,
1988. [google scholar](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=4837430613606816432&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)

Comment: Can you perhaps describe the parallelization you have in mind or at least add a link to a description?

Comment: @JanHudec I added a reference to the paper I read. But I'm open to any other parallelization approach.